# Need help with NHibernate assembly version issue. Error with loading the correct assembly version

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

**NOTE** I closed my other ticket that was to localized.

So I am having a problem like I see other posters have had after using NuGet to install FluentNhibernate:

**ERROR**

```
Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate, Version=3.0.0.2001, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's 
manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 
0x80131040)
```

I saw that on stackOverflow answers and other blogs the answer was:

```
Add-BindingRedirect
```

However, this has not resolved my issue and all the results of running that command is:

```
PM> Add-BindingRedirect

Name                                     OldVersion                                                      NewVersion                                                     
----                                     ----------                                                      ----------                                                     
NHibernate                               0.0.0.0-3.0.0.4000                                              3.0.0.4000
```

When I am installing Fluent Nhibernate from NuGet, it says its dependencies are Nhibernate 3.0.0.2001 but it installs Nhibernate 3.0.0.4000

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

I can't comment on the specific problem with NuGet but you should be able to get around the error by the adding an assembly binding redirect to your app.config or web.config.

You might want to check the public key tokey there is correct.

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Nhibernate" publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.0.0.2001" newVersion="3.0.0.4000"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

That should redirect all requests for the for 2001 to 4000

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error (Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate, Version=3.0.0.2001).  The publicKeyToken is correct.

Comment: Afraid I'm not sure what else you can try. If you copied the above exactly you might need to change name="Nhibernate" to name="NHibernate", my type there so sorry about that.

Comment: I didn't copy it.  I just updated the Oldversion and newVersion attributes since it already added the "Binding Redirect" node when I ran the Add-BindingRedirect.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how many web projects you have, and which is your start project setup, is basic, but I had the same problem with my test method and I discovered that my app.config of my test project didn't have the binding redirect.

In my case the Add-BindingRedirect command generate something like this

```
 <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate" publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.4000" newVersion="3.0.0.4000" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

This solved my problem, I hope this helps.